# avcapturesession stoprunning takes very long time

Tags: ios, objective-c, zxing, avcapturesession

I have application, that is using Zxing. when user enter to scanner page, then zxing is initializing instantly, without pressing any "scan" button. 
Ok, so I was facing problem similar to this one: 
[AVCaptureSession - Stop Running - take a long long time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11905505/avcapturesession-stop-running-take-a-long-long-time)
suggested solution is working. 
Unfortunately, when user do some quick action, e.g. go to settings page (with is stopping capture) and quick go back to scanner page (with is starting capturing), application crash.

I solved this by stooping camera in async dispacher on my custom queue, and initializing it on sync dispatcher on the same queue. It work fine, until initialization is called before camera is stop. In this case, init code is waiting on end of camera stop block, BUT this second one took ~10 second! (usual it takes around 1-2). I have no idea what's going on.

Have You any suggestion?

here is code:

```
    - (void)stopCapture
{
#if HAS_AVFF
  decoding = NO;
 [self.prevLayer removeFromSuperlayer];

    dispatch_async(myQueue, ^{
        NSLog(@"stop capture");
      [captureSession stopRunning];
        NSLog(@"session Stopped");
        if(captureSession.inputs.count>0)
        {
              AVCaptureInput* input = [captureSession.inputs objectAtIndex:0];
              [captureSession removeInput:input];
        }
        if(captureSession.outputs.count>0)
        {
              AVCaptureVideoDataOutput* output = (AVCaptureVideoDataOutput*)[captureSession.outputs objectAtIndex:0];
              [captureSession removeOutput:output];
        }

  self.prevLayer = nil;
  self.captureSession = nil;

        NSLog(@"end stop capture");
    });

#endif
}

- (void)initCapture {
dispatch_sync(myQueue, ^{
    NSLog(@"init capture");
    #if HAS_AVFF
      AVCaptureDeviceInput *captureInput =
        [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:
                [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] 
                                              error:nil];
        if(!captureInput)
        {
            NSLog(@"ERROR - CaptureInputNotInitialized");
        }


      AVCaptureVideoDataOutput *captureOutput = [[AVCaptureVideoDataOutput alloc] init]; 
      captureOutput.alwaysDiscardsLateVideoFrames = YES;
        if(!captureOutput)
        {
            NSLog(@"ERROR - CaptureOutputNotInitialized");
        }


      [captureOutput setSampleBufferDelegate:self queue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];

      NSString* key = (NSString*)kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey; 
      NSNumber* value = [NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInt:kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA];

      NSDictionary* videoSettings = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:value forKey:key];

      [captureOutput setVideoSettings:videoSettings]; 
      self.captureSession = [[[AVCaptureSession alloc] init] autorelease];
      self.captureSession.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetMedium; // 480x360 on a 4

        if([self.captureSession canAddInput:captureInput])
        {
            [self.captureSession addInput:captureInput];
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"ERROR - cannot add input");
        }
        if([self.captureSession canAddOutput:captureOutput])
        {
            [self.captureSession addOutput:captureOutput];
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"ERROR - cannot add output");
        }

      [captureOutput release];

      if (!self.prevLayer)
      {
          [self.prevLayer release];
      }
      self.prevLayer = [AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer layerWithSession:self.captureSession];

      self.prevLayer.frame = self.view.bounds;
      self.prevLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill;
      [self.view.layer addSublayer: self.prevLayer];

      [self.captureSession startRunning];
    #endif
    NSLog(@"end init");
    });
```

}